# How to keep on track with large numerals

Tags: числительные

To be entirely frank, I'm a native speaker, but for the overwhelming majority of my day I only use English, and my Russian has started to wane. My job requires me to cycle through a couple of financial transactions a day and those tend to include the pronounced statements of order numbers and sums of money. I tend to get away with saying order numbers digit by digit, yet sums of money? That gets me very odd looks.

If I take a very long while, like 5 minutes, I can finally conjure up the *"в сумме сорока шести тысяч семиста девяносто восьми рублей двух копеек"* that is needed, but the delay is as painful and long as to cause issues.

I am seeking advice from people who have learned this language intentionally: What do you do to refresh and keep up with the complex numerals? My head has been overheating because of this. Maybe an exercise or something? I don't have my old Russian language school textbooks to fall back on.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145389/discussion-on-question-by-blasphemousbanana-how-to-keep-on-track-with-large-nume); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I may be so bold, I'd like to suggest another solution — sorry if it's inappropriate.

Don't decline the numerals.

If you preface the numerical phrase with a generalizing word such as сумма, долг, заказ, стоимость, цена, итог, etc., you can leave the subsequent chain of numerals in its basic form: *"в сумме сорок шесть тысяч семьсот девяносто восемь рублей две копейки"*.

The declension of compound numerals is more of a potential grammatical possibility than an actual usage. Such compound numerals in different cases are difficult both to pronounce and to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you keep this tool bookmarked, the pauses won't be as painful?

- https://morpher.ru/SummaPro.aspx

Otherwise, practice makes perfect, as they say.